# Customizing core block toolbars

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to determine whether or not it's possible to customize options in the toolbar on a block by block basis. No matter what I try, the formats are removed from every block. Maybe there's a filter or function or something else that I'm not aware of or overlooking.

The following code is what I started with, which removes all formats globally. I've spent more time than I care to admit trying to remove bold and italic only from core/heading, and removing a few others specifically on core/paragraph.

If anyone can point me in the right (or better) direction that'd be greatly appreciated!

```
wp.data.dispatch('core/rich-text').removeFormatTypes([
  'core/annotation',
  'core/code',
  'core/bold',
  'core/footnote',
  'core/image',
  'core/italic',
  'core/keyboard',
  'core/language',
  'core/subscript',
  'core/superscript',
  'core/strikethrough',
  'core/text-color',
  'core/underline',
  'core/unknown',
])
```